# VLC with VB NET: How to rotate stream/video 180°? (Tools-Effects-Geometry-Zoom-Transform)

Tags: vb.net, vlc

I'm working with "AxVLCPlugin21" Through VB.Net and I can do the basic stuff like play, pause, etc. But now I want to rotate a video 180° but i cant find info about this, can you help me with a working example for vb net?

Thank you all.

Comment: Image or stream, your title and question is different.

Comment: A youtube stream, I'll fix the title. Thanks

Comment: vlc has the "rotate" filter, from command line you can run it like [this](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/rotate/)

Comment: Thanks, I applied it in VB.Net like this: AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("--video-filter", "rotate{angle=123}", "file:///D:\video.mp4")
            AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.play()  But nothing, can you tell me what is my mistake?

Comment: there are lots of different settings for VLC mediaplayer, plugin and etc. I am also stuck.

Answer (score 0):

From  [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/#Playlist_object) I assume you should do something like:

```
var options = new Array("--video-filter rotate{angle=180}");
// Or: var options = "--video-filter rotate{angle=180}";
var id = vlc.playlist.add("file:///D:\video.mp4", "fancy name", options);
```

or maybe

```
var options = new Array(":video-filter=rotate{angle=180}");
// Or: var options = ":video-filter=rotate{angle=180}";
var id = vlc.playlist.add("file:///D:\video.mp4", "fancy name", options);
```

Comment: Thanks but nothing happens :(